# Tic Tac Toe Generating Combinations of Boards C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, tic-tac-toe

**Note:** This is for a class assignment and has to be done this way, I know it's inefficient and I'm not asking for my homework to be done, I just need some guidance as to what I'm doing wrong.

I'd like to create a function that generates all possible combinations of tic tac toe boards in the format "xoxxooxox" with every three letters representing a row of the board. I need it to return a vector when I call the function.

What I have so far is a **loop** that generates every possible 9 digit combination of 0,1 and 2 up until 19683 which is just 3^9 combination of boards. I then have it convert 0 to # (which means an empty space), 1 to "o", and 2 to "x".

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
vector<string> get_all_boards() {

  vector<int> numboard;
  std::string board;
  for(int i = 0; i < 19683; ++i) {
    int c = i;
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j) {

      int playnum = c % 3;
        if (playnum == 0) {
        playnum = 35;
        numboard.push_back(playnum);
      } else if (playnum == 1) {
        playnum = 111;
        numboard.push_back(playnum);
      } else if (playnum == 2) {
        playnum = 120;
        numboard.push_back(playnum);
      }
      c /= 3;
    }
    for (auto x : numboard) {
      board += static_cast<char>(x);
    }
    std::copy( board.begin(), board.end(), std::back_inserter(numboard));
  }
}
int main() {
  get_all_boards();
}
```

I'm not sure how to check to see if it's outputting what I want and I get an error for "bad allocation." Is there a more efficient way to do this and how do I fix the bad allocation error?

Comment: board is a vector of strings that you are trying to put an int into

Comment: You know that a lot of those 19683 combinations aren't possible right? e.g. "xoooooooo"...

Comment: Adding to what @John3136 says, you need to eliminate already won/drawn  positions (no point in playing on) and take into account rotations and reflections which will remove a lot of duplicate positions.

Comment: use minimax algorithm to solve best possible move

Comment: your problem (technically) is that you try to put an int into an vector of string (see Mitchel0022s comment), your logic problem is that you try to create an absolutly unreasonable result vector (every possible combination on the board doen't help you). You need a minimax algorithm (see seccpurs comment) -> a function what tells you if some1 has won! https://www.neverstopbuilding.com/blog/2013/12/13/tic-tac-toe-understanding-the-minimax-algorithm13

Comment: I will later have to run through the vector and see which combinations are invalid, one's where x won, one's where o won, etc. Right now I'm just confused on how to do this. I also, unfortunately, cannot use algorithms

Comment: you don't static_cast int's to char to get the string representation of an int.  casting an int to a char converts using the ASCII table.

Answer (score 0):

For tic-tac-toe, generating **every** possible combination of X's and O's is overkill. Since the players alternate, a completely filled board would have exactly 5 X's and 4 O's. So to generate a bunch of boards, just start with a simple board and generate all possible permutations:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string board = "XXXXXOOOO";
    std::sort(std::begin(board), std::end(board));
    do {
        std::cout << board << '\n';
    } while (std::next_permutation(std::begin(board), std::end(board));
    return 0;
}
```

Note, however, that many of these boards represent impossible positions. The initial one, for example, is impossible, because it has three X's in a row and three O's in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the player enters "x" first, the number of combinations are a lot lower than you think,

- Let A denote the number of "x"s
- Let B denote the number of "o"s

Than A = B+1 or A=B

so you have to consider the following permutations:

- A = 0, B = 0
- A = 1, B = 0
- A = 1, B = 1
- A = 2, B = 1
- A = 2, B = 2

and so on,

and for each case the number of permutations can be calculated as follows:

9!/( (9-A-B)!*A!*B!)

for example if A = 3 and B = 2
for the first X: 9 choices
for the second X: 8 choices
for the third X: 7 choices
for the first O: 6 choices
for the second O: 5 choices

which is 9*8*7*6*5, which is 9!/(9-A-B)!

but we are not done, since "X"s and "O"s are identical, you have to divide it by 3! and 2!

so the total permutations for this case is 9!/(4!*3!*2!)

-A  B   Permutations

-0  0   1

-1  0   9

-1  1   72

-2  1   252

-2  2   756

-3  2   1260

-3  3   1680

-4  3   1260

-4  4   630

-5  4   126

Total = 6046

do you need the code as well?

Comment: Thank you, but this is for a class assignment so unfortunately, it needs to be done the way I outlined above. I'm just wondering what I've done wrong with my code and any way to fix it

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you all permutations, note that lots of them are not acceptable as the number of Os and number of Xs may not differ by more than one

```
{{{
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

std::string ConvertPermutationToString( int permutation )
{
    std::string board = "#########";

    int counter = 0;

    while ( permutation > 0 )
    {
        switch ( permutation %3 )
        {
        case 0: 
            //do nothing
            break;

        case 1:
            board[counter] = 'O';
            break;

        case 2:
            board[counter] = 'X';
            break;
        }

        counter++;
        permutation = permutation/3;
    }

    return board;
}
vector<string> get_all_boards() {


  std::string board;
  vector<string> allBoards;
  for(int i = 0; i < 19683; ++i) {
      allBoards.push_back( ConvertPermutationToString( i ) );
  }

  return allBoards;
}

int main() {
  get_all_boards();
}

}}}
```

Now if you want to filter out the bad combinations, use the following code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

std::string ConvertPermutationToString( int permutation )
{
    std::string board = "#########";

    int counter = 0;
    int xCount = 0;
    int oCount = 0;

    while ( permutation > 0 )
    {
        switch ( permutation %3 )
        {
        case 0: 
            //do nothing
            break;

        case 1:
            board[counter] = 'O';
            oCount++;
            break;

        case 2:
            board[counter] = 'X';
            xCount++;
            break;
        }

        counter++;
        permutation = permutation/3;
    }

    if ( abs( xCount - oCount ) > 1 ) 
    {
        board = "";
    }

    return board;
}
vector<string> get_all_boards() {


  std::string board;
  vector<string> allBoards;
  for(int i = 0; i < 19683; ++i) {

      board = ConvertPermutationToString( i );

      if ( board.length() )
      {
        allBoards.push_back( ConvertPermutationToString( i ) );
      }
  }

  return allBoards;
}

int main() {
  get_all_boards();
}
```

you have 8953 acceptable combinations